Davinci trims beginning and end of my video
I've edited a video in DaVinci Resolve 19.0.2 and I'm trying to render it but right after I click the Render button, it switches the Render mode from "Entire Timeline" to "In/Out Range" and also trims several seconds at the beginning and the end of the video. Nothing seems to be able to fix this.
I've tried copy-pasting the timeline contents into a new project and got the same problem. This is driving me insane. What is wrong with DaVinci here?


